# event emitter works one time but not a second time Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, events, dialog, angular-event-emitter

I have this variable which controls if a dialog shows up or not, it works on the first time, but not on a second time, emit excutes but the receiveing function is no longer called.

parent class:

```
  isLogin :boolean ;

  constructor(...){
    this.isLogin = false;
}
  receiveNotification(notification: boolean): void {
    this.isLogin = notification;
  }
```

parent html:

```
<login-dialog   *ngIf="!isLogin"  name="{{name}}" (notify)="receiveNotification($event)"></login-dialog>
```

in the child class:
I have a function that when triggered calls emit and emit is indeed called just doesn't trigger the function on the parent on a second time

```
@Output() notify = new EventEmitter<any>();

  exampleFunction(){
 this.notify.emit(true);
}
```

I think maybe this is connected to the ngIf but not sure,  what is wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be because you are *emitting* a true value but on the parent template you are checking for `!true` which is false.

As per your current logic, you should either emit a false value or change the condition to `*ngIf="isLogin"` in the parent template.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use hidden instead of ngIf, because ngIf remove the component from the DOM but hidden just hide it.

```
<login-dialog   [hidden]="isLogin"  name="{{name}}"...></login-dialog>
```